# Add remote eclipse installation to target platform?

Tags: eclipse, target-platform

In eclipse its possible to add a local eclipse installation to the target platform:

Window -> Preferences -> Plugin-in Development -> Target Platform -> Edit -> Add -> Installation -> [location of local eclipse installation]

But how do I add an eclipse installation located on a remote server (just copied a local eclipse installation to the webapps folder on a tomcat server)?

I have tried to specify the remote eclipse installation as an Software Site instead:

Window -> Preferences -> Plugin-in Development -> Target Platform -> Edit -> Add -> Software Site -> [url to remote eclipse location]

but that does not work.

I know that I could just add the official remote p2 eclipse sites to the target platform but I would like to use a remote "physical" installation instead (to be 100% that its always available).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

try to use target definition to define a remote location

For example, the target file is copied from toast,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<target name="Toast Target">
<locations>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeMode="slicer" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature.group" version="3.0.1.v20090916-2238"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.sdk.id" version="3.5.1.M20090917-0800"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.feature.group" version="1.1.2.v20090612-r4475"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="2.5.0.v200906151043"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.emf.teneo.eclipselink.sdk.feature.group" version="1.0.0.v200909151729-31184E43QYgJOQQRZuYI_PFWWGHN"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.5.1.r351_v20090901-7G7MAA7lQiEeE7LKsaYgOK58fdAa"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.rap.sdk.feature.group" version="1.2.1.20090813-1453"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo"/>
</location>
<location path="${workspace_loc}/Toast/target" type="Directory"/>
</locations>
<targetJRE path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
</target>
```